# Java a way to get from an angle the atan2 value (alpha)?

Tags: java, math, angle, atan2

```
  double dx = mx - px;
    double dy = my - py;
    double alpha = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(alpha);
    angle += 10;
```

Now I want to convert the angle to the alpha value (atan2) is there a way how i can do that?

The purpose is that I have a game an want to fire bullets with a variation of the degree like a shotgun.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Just the inverse of `Math.toDegrees()`, i.e. `Math.toRadians()`?

Comment: Exactly so I can use the new alpha value with the added degrees

Comment: And what prevents you from using `Math.toRadians()`?

Comment: Thanks that was I was looking for, doesn't think it is that easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double newalpha = Math.toRadians(angle);
```